# It is nor max/min code how do i figure out this code?

Tags: c++

get a program that gets  (three integers ) and display the value that is neither max nor min ?

I tried to think of a way to get a number between max and min. My input is x,y,z which are (three integers ) how to get this number which is neither max nor min ?

```
int x,y,z,max,min,between;
cout<<"enter 3 integer values \n";
cin>>x>>y>>z,between;

if (x>y&&x>z)
    x=max;
else if (x<y&&x<z)
    x=min;
else if(y>z&&y>x)
    y=max;
else if (y<z&&y<x)
    y=min;
else if(!max==between&& !min==between)
    cout<<"not max or min is "<<between<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

will I know that this is not the right code but I know that the path is somewhere close .

Comment: I don't know what is the wrong with code I am trying to write a proper one help me to edit it .

Comment: Just copy and paste code here, then select all of your code and press Ctrl+K or click the braces icon `{ }` on the bar.

Comment: Use `std::max({x, y, z})` and `std::min({x, y, z})`.

Answer (score 1):

> get a number between max and min. input (three integers )

This is essentially the median of the three numbers.

A simple solution can be to take the elements in an array, sort them and then pick the middle element, like so,

```cpp
int elements[3] = ... // contains x,y,z
std::sort(std::begin(elements), std::end(elements)); // sorts the elements
elements[1] // pick the middle element
```

I am assuming that all the numbers are distinct otherwise there is no number which is neither min nor max. For example, of the three numbers are 3, 3 and 3, 3 is both the min and max. There is no solution in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you compare the first 2 variable to see witch of them is the max value and after that just compare with the other variable

```
if (x < y) 
{
    if (z < x)  
    {
        return x;
    }
    else if(z < y) {
        return z;
    }
    else {
        return y;
    }

}
else if (y < z) 
{
    if (z < x) {
        return z;
    }
    else {
        return y;
    }
}
```